# ¿Es posible enviar un correo a cualquier email en PHP con PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

tengo una duda y es que si es posible que con PHPMailer se puede enviar un correo a cualquier correo que se introduzca en el formulario

Saludos!

Comment: La respuesta es: Si, es posible, aunque mejor buscate otra libreria.

Comment: Que libreria???

Comment: https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sí que es posible** y además es la librería más popular de PHP para realizar esta tarea. En [PHPMailer GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) tienes tanto los pasos de instalación como un ejemplo básico para enviar emails, donde podrás añadir tantas direcciones de correo electrónico de destino como desees por cada mail:

```
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User'); // Ejemplo con nombre
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');           // Ejemplo sin nombre
```

**Aplicado a un formulario sería:**

```
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']); // Ejemplo con nombre
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);                 // Ejemplo sin nombre
```

**Alternativa:** Hay otras librerías también muy buenas como [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/). Recomiendo que las pruebes las 2 y te quedes con la que más a gusto estés, porque en cuanto a características y rendimiento son muy similares.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda lo agradezco!

Comment: @JosepGiner De nada! Si el post ha resuelto completamente tus dudas puedes marcarlo como aceptado para ayudar a otros usuarios. Gracias